# Is there a Maven plugin or similar tool that can configure a running Tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, maven, containers, configuration-management

My organization wants to put "configuration" of the container (such as JMS resources and datasources) into source control. I'd like haven Maven be able to execute this as a goal. This isn't far from the underlying ideas behind liquibase, where you can update your schema with `mvn liquibase:update`.

I'd like something that could be like:

```
mvn container:config -Pdev
```

and it would go out to the dev server and perhaps add a datasource to the server.xml. Bonus points if the solution is portable across GlassFish.

Anyone know of a tool like this?

Comment: Is your goal to manipulate xml, and the fact that it's for Tomcat is just a detail?

Comment: No, assume I don't have access to the tomcat filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there does not appear to be a ready-made tool that does this. You probably will have to do something with [Maven Antrun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) that executes a script to logon to the Tomcat server (i.e. via ssh) and manipulate the `server.xml` file directly.

I might use a combination of [Ant SCP Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) and [XML Task](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put run-time configuration under version control consider using tools like:

- [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)
- [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/)

It's possible to use Maven to run your deployments, but you'd be better advised to deploy your application to a Maven repository (like Nexus) and then download from there during deployment. That way you avoid re-compiling your code everytime you want to install your application.

Comment: Agreed, Maven is a great build tool - not so much for runtime configuration management. BTW another option is PalletOps - http://palletops.com/

Comment: @noahz There are plenty of options. The more I work with deployments the more I think a dedicated solution is required. For an interesting open source tool chain (plus reasons why) I recommend reading the following link: http://dev2ops.org/2012/05/using-rundeck-and-chef-to-build-devops-toolchains-at-chefcon/